# When installing node 14.18.1 using nvm my mac uses python 3.9 and throws error on installation

Tags: python, macos, nvm

I have an m1 mac with big surr.
I needed node v14 to run an old angular app. i had nodev16 ialraedy installed so i tried to install nvm . installed successfully and i have no problem installing any of the different versions of node v16 but when installing node 14.18.1 it is using python 3.9 for some weird reason.
I have installed python before  is it by mistake using python 3.9 instead of 2.7

also i am searching internet and stack overflow and i read that node v14 cant be run on m1 mac is this true?

can someone please tell how to solve this error.

```
nvm install 14.18.1
Downloading and installing node v14.18.1...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.18.1/node-v14.18.1-darwin-arm64.tar.xz...

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 
Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.18.1/node-v14.18.1-darwin-arm64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /Users/rohitkrishnamoorthy/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.18.1-darwin-arm64/node-v14.18.1-darwin-arm64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Detected that you have 8 CPU core(s)
Running with 7 threads to speed up the build
Clang v3.5+ detected! CC or CXX not specified, will use Clang as C/C++ compiler!
Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v14.18.1/node-v14.18.1.tar.xz
Checksums match! Using existing downloaded archive ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v14.18.1/node-v14.18.1.tar.xz
$>./configure --prefix=/Users/rohitkrishnamoorthy/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.1 <
Node.js configure: Found Python 3.9.6...
INFO: configure completed successfully
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=0
  touch /Users/rohitkrishnamoorthy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.18.1/files/out/Release/obj.target/node_dtrace_header.stamp
  touch /Users/rohitkrishnamoorthy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.18.1/files/out/Release/obj.target/specialize_node_d.stamp
  c++ -o /Users/rohitkrishnamoorthy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.18.1/files/out/Release/obj.target/icuucx/deps/icu-small/source/common/uniset.o ../deps/icu-small/source/common/uniset.cpp '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION=1' '-DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED=' '-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=' '-DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION=1' '-DUCONFIG_NO_SERVICE=1' '-DU_ENABLE_DYLOAD=0' '-DU_HAVE_STD_STRING=1' '-DUCONFIG_NO_BREAK_ITERATION=0' -I../deps/icu-small/source/common  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++1y -stdlib=libc++ -fno-exceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF /Users/rohitkrishnamoorthy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.18.1/files/out/Release/.deps//Users/rohitkrishnamoorthy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.18.1/files/out/Release/obj.target/icuucx/deps/icu-small/source/common/uniset.o.d.raw   -c
  c++ -o /Users/rohitkrishnamoorthy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.18.1/files/out/Release/obj.target/icuucx/deps/icu-small/source/common/dictbe.o ../deps/icu-small/source/common/dictbe.cpp '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION=1' '-DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED=' '-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=' '-DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION=1' '-DUCONFIG_NO_SERVICE=1' '-DU_ENABLE_DYLOAD=0' '-DU_HAVE_STD_STRING=1' '-DUCONFIG_NO_BREAK_ITERATION=0' -I../deps/icu-small/source/common  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=gnu++1y -stdlib=libc++ -fno-exceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF /Users/rohitkrishnamoorthy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.18.1/files/out/Release/.deps//Users/rohitkrishnamoorthy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.18.1/files/out/Release/obj.target/icuucx/deps/icu-small/source/common/dictbe.o.d.raw   -c
  c++ -o /Users/rohitkrishnamoorthy/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.18.1/files/out/Release/obj.target/icuucx/deps/icu-small/source/common/chariter.o ../deps/icu-small/source/common/chariter.cpp '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION=1' '-DU_ATTRIBUTE_DEPRECATED=' '-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=' '-DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION=1' '-DUCONFIG_NO_SERVICE=1' '-DU_ENA
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to uninstall python 3.9 and install Python 2.7.18.

Node 14.18.1 does work on m1 mac but if you update to Monterey 12.3, the pre-installed Python will be removed. So you might have to install it again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).